# Spring Boot Security UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter does not limit the login url to only POST

Tags: spring, http, security, authentication, post

I looked all throughout and nobody else is having this issue that I can find. The authentication works correctly but the login url works on any HTTP method (GET, PUT, etc) vs. only working on POST. I tried manually setting `filter.setPostOnly(true);` on the custom JWTAuthenticationFilter I made, but it still allows on all methods.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final String FILTER_PROCESS_URL = "/authentication";
    private static final String HEALTH_RESOURCE_URL = "/health/**";

    private CustomUserDetailService userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurityConfig(CowCalfUserDetailService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, FILTER_PROCESS_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, HEALTH_RESOURCE_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(getJWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManagerBean()))
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter getJWTAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        final JWTAuthenticationFilter filter = new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean());
        filter.setPostOnly(true);
        filter.setFilterProcessesUrl(FILTER_PROCESS_URL);
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Comment: After the line `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, FILTER_PROCESS_URL).permitAll()` can you try adding these lines
`.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, FILTER_PROCESS_URL).denayAll()
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, FILTER_PROCESS_URL).denayAll()`  ?

Comment: Well, yes I can do that but I dont want to have to blacklist all HTTP methods since UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class should do that for me.

Comment: Of course, it should do it. As it is not doing, for debugging I wanted you to do so. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I figured out what it was. I answered the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59580729/7107589

Answer (score 1):

I found out how `setPostOnly()` works.  `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication()` checks for POST before attempting the authentication and throws an exception. This method I have overridden with my custom `JWTAuthenticationFilter`. I just did the same and added a check in my overridden method too. Thank you for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you  correctly, you want to limit the /authentication only to the POST Http-Method. If yes, you could achieve it by adding the following code snippet to your method in the "RestController" for the Authentication:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authentication", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

[RequestMapping Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)

Comment: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter provides the login resource for me. `filter. setFilterProcessesUrl` is how you can change the endpoint path. By default it is "/login".